# What software did Elon Musk use for the SpaceX presentation

Tags: graphic-design, presentation, animation

I just watched the [presentaton](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tdUX3ypDVwI) on "Making Life Multiplanetary" by Elon Musk. I wonder what software they are using. I especially want to point out the pretty animations with the different payloads for the rockets (13:58) and the descent animation with the plot (35:39). Do they use prerendered animations? The wireframe animation was so obviously, but also the plot?

I usually create my presentations with beamer (LaTex) and the Metropolis style. This gives me a nice and uniform look for the whole presentation. How do I achieve a uniform line thickness when importing graphics from other programs? With tikz its really easy.

Comment: I had the same question while watching the presentation!

Comment: Can you edit your title to be a more specific summary of your interest/needs?

Comment: I don’t know exactly what you mean. An answer could be like „He is using PowerPoint 2020 with those new awesome features“ or „All animations are prerendered and put in as video into the presentation“.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/SpaceXLounge/comments/74a5ri/what_presentation_software_does_elon_use/) on Reddit somebody saw the presentation running on a Mac and therefore suspects them to use Apple Keynote.

Comment: They used keynote in the past, but this presentation was just on another level. Also there is no clear answer to the question on that thread.